# Script grasemonkey quitar espacio en link tel:

Tags: javascript

Necesito quitar un espacio de un link a telefono; la estructura del html es esta:

```
<a id="phone1" href="tel:+34 915555555"> +34 915555555</a>
<a id="phone2" href="tel:+34 666555444"> +34 666555444</a>
```

El problema que tengo es que el programa que se usa para las llamadas es algo limitado; tengo un dial plan que en internet explorer funciona, ya que el link que genera es así +34%20666555444 y mediante el dial plan lo puedo cambiar y bien.
Pero chrome y firefox el link que mandan es algo como: +34 ( y no se que más, porque no lo captura ).
Probando a editar manualmente el número ( quitando el espacio ) se enlaza bien con el programa y genial. Había pensado en usar un script de greasemonkey/tampermonkey pero tengo muy poco conocimiento de javascript y no doy con como hacerlo.
Me gustaría que quedase algo así:

```
<a id="phone1" href="tel:+34915555555"> +34 915555555</a>
<a id="phone2" href="tel:+34666555444"> +34 666555444</a>
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano; se lo agradezco.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que te ha dicho @alfabravo, podrías empezar por buscar algún ejemplo de greasemonkey script que se aproxime un poco a lo que intentas acerca de procesar enlaces.

Answer (score 0):

Primero se hace una lista con todos los que tengan la etiqueta `a`.

```
var lista = document.querySelectorAll("a")
```

Luego se convierte la lista a un array:

```
var array = Array.from(lista)
```

Se itera y se ejecuta una función para cada elemento.

```
array.map(function(a){})
```

Por último se reemplaza el `href` quitándole los espacios:

```
a.href.replace(/\s+/g,"");
```

Código final:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Cambia href
// @namespace   espacio
// @description Quita los espacios al href
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map(function(a){
    return a.href = a.href.replace(/\s+/g,"");
})
```